# python replace multiple characters in a string

Tags: python-3.x

I want to encrypt a string in python. Every character in the char is mapped to some other character in the secret key. For example `'a'` is mapped to `'D'`, 'b' is mapped to `'d'`, `'c'` is mapped to `'1'` and so forth as shown below:

```
char    = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
secretkey="Dd18Abz2EqNPWhYTOjBvtVlpXaH6msFUICg4o0KZwJeryQx3f9kSinRu5L7cGM"
```

If I choose the string `"Lets meet at the usual place at 9 am"` the output must be `"oABjMWAABMDBMB2AMvjvDPMYPD1AMDBMGMDW"`

Comment: Could you post what you've done so far?

Comment: I'm curious as to how much security this would provide? Over on security SE they always recommend using third-party encryption options and not trying to reinvent the wheel. Have you researched encryption before doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As for replacing multiple characters in a string**

You can use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
>>> char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
>>> secretkey = "Dd18Abz2EqNPWhYTOjBvtVlpXaH6msFUICg4o0KZwJeryQx3f9kSinRu5L7cGM"
>>> trans = str.maketrans(char, secretkey)  
>>> s = "Lets meet at the usual place at 9 am"
>>> s.translate(trans)
'0AvB WAAv Dv v2A tBtDP TPD1A Dv M DW'
```

or if you prefer to preserve only those in `char`:

```
>>> ''.join(c for c in s if c in char).translate(trans)
'0AvBWAAvDvv2AtBtDPTPD1ADvMDW'
```

**As for encrypting**

I would recommend using a dedicated library for that, such as [pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am making two assumptions here.

1. I think the output you expect is wrong, for instance `L` should be mapped to `0`, not to `o`, right?
2. I am assuming you want to ignore whitespace, since it is not included in your mapping.

So then the code would be:

```
to_encrypt = "Lets meet at the usual place at 9 am"
char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
secretkey = "Dd18Abz2EqNPWhYTOjBvtVlpXaH6msFUICg4o0KZwJeryQx3f9kSinRu5L7cGM"
encrypted = ""

for c in to_encrypt:
    if c in char:
        encrypted += secretkey[char.index(c)]

print(encrypted)
```

The output would be:

```
0AvBWAAvDvv2AtBtDPTPD1ADvMDW
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With your help i solve the problem